# setTimeout inside component is getting called regardless of page

Tags: react-native, redux, react-native-router-flux

I have a setTimeout call that gets called every 5 minutes. The issue is that no matter what page I am on, the timeout is still getting called and is making api calls.

My setTimeout component is inside the home page, what would be ideal is killing just that component when no longer on the home page. I would like to avoid destroying the homepage component and not having to refetch data.

My setTimeout code is like this:

```
    sendCords(){
       this.props.actions.findCords()
       this.beginTimeout()
    }

    beginTimeout(){
       let timer = setTimeout(this.sendCords,300000);
       this.setState({timer});
    }
```

Note: Lifecycle hooks E.G. componentWillUnMount is not getting called, as the pages are like a stack - and the pages are not un-mounting. I am using react-native-router-flux

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The issue is componentWillUnmount is not getting called, because when I navigate to another page, it is like a stack, where one page goes ontop of the other

Answer (score 0):

Well I ended up having to do a few things, in my actions I would check what page I was calling and dispatch an empty action if It was not called on the homepage. This would trigger a the clear timeout. Having a force refresh on my component was needed

```
<Comp refresh={() => this.setState({val:!this.state.val} />
```

And I would then I have a shouldComponentUpdate used like so when navigating back to the home page and needing to set the timeout again:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState){
    if(this.props.removeTimer && !nextState.removeTimer){
        this.timeOutFunc()
}
```